# Short-form links to Q&A don't show up in the "Linked" question list in the sidebar

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

Links in comments (and maybe in answers) in the short form do not show up in the "Linked" questions list in the right sidebar:

```
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/nnn
```

Links that use the full form do show up:

```
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/nnn
```

The same happens for short and long form answer links.

Examples:

1. The links in [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179401/generating-list-of-labeled-string#comment469107_179401)  from September show up in the sidebar.
2. The link in [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187647/nintegrate-weird-behaviour-inside-a-function#comment488401_187647)  from a few days ago does not show up in the sidebar.

I don't know if this is intentional, but it makes the short form seem deprecated.  Can the old functionality be restored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'oh! It's because I was using an old script to generate the link.  The script used the defunct HTTP protocol.  Switching it to HTTPS fixes the problem.